# timeout loop in promise never executes after promise is resolved?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise, event-loop

I'm running into an issue where a callback sent to `setTimeout` from a resolved promise never get executed.

supposed I have the following:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  async execUntilStop(callback) {
    const timeoutLoopCallback = () => {
      if (this.stopExec) return;
      callback({ data: 'data' });
      setTimeout(timeoutLoopCallback, 10);
    };
    setTimeout(timeoutLoopCallback, 10);

    return { data: 'data'};
  }

  stop() {
    this.stopExec = true;
  }
}

const myFunc = async function () {
  let callbackCalled = false;
  const callback = () => callbackCalled = true;
  foo = new Foo('foo');
  foo.execUntilStop(callback);
  const hasCallbackCalled = async () => callbackCalled;

  while(!(await hasCallbackCalled())) null;
  foo.stop();
  return 'success!';
};

myFunc().then((result) => console.log(result))
```

`myFunc()` never resolves as it is continually waiting for `callbackCalled` to be `true`.

What am I missing here?  I believe the event loop shouldn't be blocked since I'm calling await on an async function to check if the callback has been called. I hypothesise it has something to do with `timeoutLoopCallback` being bound to a resolved promise but I'm not a javascript expert and could use some feedback.

Note: This looks a little odd but essentially this is derivative of a class I'm trying to write test cases for that will be continually executing a callback until stopped.

---

**SOLVED**

Using what I learned from @traktor53 answer, I wrote a handy dandy `wait` function:

```
// resolves when callback returns true
const wait = callback => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const end = () => {
    try {
      if (callback()) {
        resolve(true);
      } else {
        setTimeout(end, 0);
      }
    } catch(error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  };
  setTimeout(end, 0);
});


class Foo {
  constructor(foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  async execUntilStop(callback) {
    const timeoutLoopCallback = () => {
      if (this.stopExec) return;
      callback({ data: 'data' });
      setTimeout(timeoutLoopCallback, 10);
    };
    setTimeout(timeoutLoopCallback, 10);

    return { data: 'data'};
  }

  stop() {
    this.stopExec = true;
  }
}

const myFunc = async function (num) {
  let callbackCalled = false;
  const callback = () => callbackCalled = true;
  foo = new Foo('foo');
  foo.execUntilStop(callback);

  const hasCallbackCalled = () => callbackCalled;
  await wait(hasCallbackCalled);
  foo.stop();
  return 'success!';
};

myFunc().then((result) => console.log(result)); // => success!
```

Comment: I don't see a Promise here.

Comment: > async function Return value:

A Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an uncaught exception thrown from within the async function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function @PHPglue

Comment: @CRice  Yes meant to use `await hasCallbackCalled()`.  an oversight when I was making this isolated example of the issue.

Comment: I don't think the updated code would be any different to be honest, you're still just dealing with syncrhonous "Promise"

Comment: @JaromandaX Correct me if I'm mistaken but `await` allows other code to run until the promise passed to `await` is resolved, right?  So this wouldn't be "synchronous \"Promise\"" , it just more readable.

Comment: does the code work? if not, then you have your answer

Comment: @JaromandaX it's not synchronous https://gist.github.com/rudolph9/e8f816045cf113d4b8a675d3c565dea1

Comment: Yeah, but due to the high priority microtask queue it may as well be :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169809/discussion-between-rudolph9-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: `setImmediate` - so, this code is for node, ie and/ro Edge only?

Comment: @JaromandaX <strike>yeah this is node. I'll add a tag.</strike> actually I'll just change it to setTimeout

Comment: all good, you dont' have to, just pointing out `setImmediate`s "limitation" :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jobs to handle promise settlement go into a "Promise Job Queue" (PJQ) described in ECMAScript standards. This nomenclature is not often used in HTML documentation.

Browsers (and at least one script engine) put jobs for the PJQ into what is commonly called the "Micro Task Queue" (MTQ). The event loop task manager checks the MTQ on return from script callout from the event loop, to see if it has any jobs in it, and will pop and executes the oldest job in the queue if there is one. The line in the original post

```
 while(!(await callbackCalled)) null;
```

(which in the first call is equivalent to

```
while( !( await Promise.resolve( false));  // callbackCalled is false
```

)

puts a job to get the settled value of the promise returned by Promise.resolve,  into the MTQ and continue executing by having the `await` operator return the fulfilled value, which is `false`.

Because browsers process the MTQ at a higher priority than tasks generated by timer expiry, execution continues after the `await` operation and immediately executes another iteration of the loop and puts another job into the MTQ to await the `false` value, *without processing any timer call backs in between*.

This sets up an asynchronous infinite loop ( congratulations BTW, I havn't seen one before!), and under these conditions I would not expect the timer call back to execute and call `timeoutLoopCallback` a second time.

The infinite loop is also blocking continuation to the next line:

```
  foo.stop()
```

never executes.

Note the blocking effect observed here is a consequence of the HTML implementation of the "Promise Job Queue" - The ECMAScript committed chose to not specify implimentation and priority details for real JavaScript systems. So blame HTML standards, not ECMAScript :D

Also note: replacing `await calledBackCalled` with `await hasCallbackCalled()` will not fix the problem - different promise jobs will be generated, but the await operator will still return `false`.

---

(Update) Since you ask, the actual steps for

```
 while(!(await hasCallbackCalled())) null;
```

are:

1. Evaluate `hasCallbackCalled()`
2. 'hasCallbackCalled` is an async function and returns a promise fulfilled with the return value of the function body.
3. The function body is synchronous code, and fulfills the returned promise on first call by synchronously returning the value of `callbackCalled` (which is `false`)
4. The promise returned by the async function has so far been synchronously fulfilled with the value `false`.
5. `await` now adds handlers by calling `.then` on the promise obtained in step  4, to let `await` know the settled value and state (in this case "fulfilled").
6. But calling `then` on a fulfilled promise *synchronously* inserts a job to call the fulfilled handler with the fulfilled value into the MTQ
7. the MTQ now has a job to call code for this particular `await` back;
8. `await` returns to the event loop manager.
9. the MTQ job now executes the then handler added in step 5,
10. the then handler resumes `await` operator processing  which returns the value `false` to user script.
11. the while loop test continues execution from step 1.

Comment: FYI, I just updated the example to use `while( !(await hasCallbackCalled() ))`.  Your answer is good though! will you update it to reflect the fixed oversight in the question?